# Know when a user is created in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to find a way to know when a user is created in Wordpress, can anyone help me?

What I want is a function so when an admin is registered the fuction do X thing. What is X thing? I am going to take the data of that user to create an account on another platform.

Summary: I want to know when an administrator is created with a function to run another function.

Answer (score 0):

There are multilple hooks you can use. Here is a nice overview : https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-registration-hooks-visualized/

I think `user_register` is the right one for you:

```
add_action( 'user_register', function ( $user_id ) {
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;
    // you now have the role and can call your function after checking if it is admin
} );
```